# how do I deploy my site from my gitolite repo on the same server?

Tags: git, ubuntu, gitolite, vlad-deployer

I am using Sinatra, Vlad the Deployer, and Gitolite trying to deploy a test site to my server. My gitolite installation is working fine as far as managing/creating repos, push and cloning etc., but when I try to deploy via Vlad to my server, I keep getting a permissions denied error on

```
$ rake vlad:update
```

which returns

```
rake aborted!
execution failed with status 1:ssh mysite.com unmask 02 && cd ..........
```

my vlad deploy.rb file looks like this

```
#deploy.rb

set :application, "mysite.com/sample-site"
set :user,        "me"
set :repository, "git@mysite.com:sample-site.git"
set :domain, "mysite.com"
set :deploy_to, "~/sites/#{application}"
```

i think what is happening is that some how the gitolite user, named 'git', it trying to clone the repo from the server where it lives but doesn't have the proper permissions. I thought I might create a new rsa pair for user git and then just add it to the list of users in my gitolite keydir but with the gitolite install you can't ssh in any more with the "PTY 0 error" which seems to be normal.

When i would try to clone repos from the server to itself, i.e. git clone as me from a repo on the server, I would get asked for a password for git@mysite so I tried to copy my client id_rsa and id_rsa.pub to my server then add me@mysite as another user in my client gitolite-admin.conf. When I push that update it it keeps giving me an error

```
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 378 bytes, done.
Total 4 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: WARNING: a pubkey file can only have one line (key); ignoring jon@mysite.com.pub
remote:          Perhaps you're using a key in a different format (like putty/plink)?
remote:          If so, please convert it to openssh format using 'ssh-keygen -i'.
remote:          If you want to add multiple public keys for a single user, use
remote:          "user@host.pub" file names.  See the "one user, many keys"
remote:          section in doc/3-faq-tips-etc.mkd for details.
remote: 
remote:         ***** WARNING *****
remote:         the following users (pubkey files in parens) do not appear in any access rules:
remote: jon@mysite.com(jon@mysite.com.pub)
remote: 
remote:         ***** WARNING *****
remote:         the following users have no pubkeys:
remote: jon@mysite
```

I originally tried to add my new server user with me@site.com.pub but then thought switching to me@mysite.pub was cleaner and might fix some issues. Now I have some artifact from that even after deleting and/or renaming everything in the key itself and the keys' name to me@mysite.pub

So where I am at now is that I CAN clone from the server when signed in as me, but it asks for my id_rsa password each time. When i enter it, I can download. My rake vlad:update though is getting the same errors as when i start.....

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

I cant comment on vlad the deployer specifically but you should not need to do anything with keys for the git account. You need to have keys set up for the user you are running the process as. It seems this is 'user'? So you need to generate an rsa for user on that machine and add the pub key specifically.

The error you are seeing at the end of your question is a mismatch between the keys gitolite sees in your keydir vs the entries in your config file. Everything in the keydir needs to end with .pub and you reference it in the conf without .pub

Comment: thanks for the comment. So do you mean I should generate a new rsa key on the server as user git? I can ssh, and push to my repos from my client machine but when I run my vlad:update function I am getting this error   Cloning into /home/jon/sites/mysite.com/test-repo/scm/repo...
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly.   I am thinking this happening because some how vlad or git are trying to cp the depolyment files but dont have access to my /sites directory.